# Python and audiofile words detection: timestamps for recognized words is off by 2-3 seconds

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I'm trying to use PocketSphynx to find words inside a wav file. It's actually a real challenge, since the documentation is really poor (null sometimes).

```
import os
from pocketsphinx import AudioFile
from pocketsphinx import Pocketsphinx, LiveSpeech, get_model_path, get_data_path
import speech_recognition as sr


# Frames per Second
fps = 100

r = sr.Recognizer()
framerate = 100
with sr.AudioFile("audiotestcorto.wav") as source:

    audio = r.record(source)

    decoder = r.recognize_sphinx(audio, language = "en-US", show_all=True)
    
    for s in decoder.seg():
        print('| %4s s | %4s s | %8s |' % (s.start_frame ,  s.end_frame , s.word))
```

this is my code, and it doesn't throw any error (already an achievement, after some dark days :) )

The problem is that the timestamps of the words are wrong.

why timestamps are wrong? the error is around 2 - 3 seconds, and it doesn't get better even if I multiply or divide by the framerate.

Comment: You were trying to code without using the official reference/documentation? It's right [here](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst) on the official GitHub page, and of course includes info on `recognize_sphinx`. Also this question might get closed for being not focused, because you've asked like 4 questions in one. The [ask] page and this [help/on-topic] topic should clarify that your questions should be more specific.

Comment: @RandomDavis  that's not really a documentation, since a lot of parameters/functions are missing. Anyway I edited my question with the most important one I have

Comment: Where did you get "framerate = 100"?  That's not a sensible number.  Your wave file is almost certainly more like 48000 frames per second.

Comment: In the only example I found it says that framerate is 100, but I guess it does not refer to the audio file framerate, but to some kind of sampling of that file. As I mentioned, the documentation is almost zero :(